# SparqlVerse issue with Docker

Tags: docker, sparql, rhel7

I tried to setup sparqlverse (Sparql City) within a docker container. It works fine within interactive mode (i.e. interactively start the container and then start the daemon manually). However, once you quit the container and try and re-starting it or if you start a container from an image in background mode the container quits abruptly after 1 or 2 seconds. Apparently, the container logs also does not reveal anything about the abnormal termination. I have explicitly allocated about 10gig of memory to the container. My host OS is RHEL Server 7.0 (VM on Mac OSX), docker version 1.3.2 and sparqlverse single node version. Would appreciate some help if anyone has encountered and resolved this issue.

Comment: Showing your Dockerfile would be a good start.

Comment: #######################################################################
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel
MAINTAINER jaberwocky

RUN yum install -y gcc-c++
RUN yum update -y
EXPOSE 7979
#ENTRYPOINT ["/var/local/sparqlcity/sparqlverse/opt_rel/bin/sbxstart", "-port", "7979"] 
#CMD /var/local/sparqlcity/sparqlverse/opt_rel/bin/sbxstart -port 7979
#CMD ["/var/local/sparqlcity/sparqlverse/opt_rel/bin/sbxstart", "-port", "7979", "&"]
#######################################################################

Comment: I have tried with entry point, command and that too does not work. As explained earlier, this works fine within the container as long as it is in interactive mode (-i). As soon as I quit, the issue shows up. Thereafter, if I restart the container in background or save it as image and launch a container from that image it does not start the sparqlverse daemon and further abruptly terminates the container.

Comment: Looks like you have things commented out? Please edit your original question and put the Dockerfile there, so it's readable.